# JavaScript form validation in Ruby on Rails - Got JS working, but where do I put it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I created a real estate calculator in Ruby for my final project in a graduate school class. The project is due in about 24 hours (on Monday) so I really appreciate the help.

The app runs great but I need to add client side form validation using JS. I got the JS to work just like I want it to in a basic html form but now I need to apply this JS functionality to the form that our group's been using in the Ruby on Rails environment.

I'm not sure how to merge these two forms exactly and where to put the JS so that the init functions do not overwrite each other or cause an error. I would assume that all the JS code goes in the App/assets/javascript folder but I'm a bit confused about how the JS links correctly to each form I'm creating because I have to do this for three forms because I have three entities: an investor entity, a property entity and a mortgage entity.

I got all the JS validation working locally for each of these three entities and I pasted *the one for mortgage below*. They're each in their own separate folders when I created and tested the JS validations locally, but on the ruby git repo, I think all the JS code shares the same JS folder in a way that... well I don't know much about JS in RoR yet, but I assume that all the JS in that assets/js folder is active.

I'm worried because if I throw all of my JS validation code in that folder or combine it into a single file, then would there be a conflict if all three of the entities are calling a function with the same name ("initPage")?

So... hmmm.. I guess if I just rename this initPage() to 3 separate functions, like this:

- initInvestorPage()
- initMortgagePage()
- initPropertyPage()

**QUESTIONS:**

would this be the correct way to go or how else would it know which initPage() to call?

how do the traditional html form and the Ruby form_for merge gracefully?

I pasted below all the JS code needed to work but actually only the warning definitions and the one function initPage() are different for each entity. I would assume the utils.js can just be placed in the assets/js folder but how about the other JS code for the three entities?

Do I (?):

- option 1) combine it all into one custom.js file and rename the initPage into three separate functions.. OR
- option 2) keep the js files separate and somehow call them separately depending on which form is calling
- option 3) go some other way with it...
- option 4) take a long walk off a short pier the day before final's week

Thx!!

**Mortgage form in Ruby that I need to add JS validation: (sorry for all the markup that's from using Bootstrap)**

```
<% provide(:title, 'Create mortgage') %>
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Create mortgage</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row"> 
    <%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %> 
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <%= form_for(@mortgage) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <fieldset class="property_create_group">    
              <label for="mortgage_name">Mortgage name</label>
              <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "form-control" %>
            </fieldset>
          </div>           
          <div class="col-md-2 clear-both1">
            <fieldset class="property_create_group">    
              <label for="mortgage_amount">Amount</label>
              <%= f.number_field :amount, :class => "form-control" %>          
            </fieldset>
          </div>  
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <fieldset class="property_create_group">    
              <label for="mortgage_terms">Term (yr)</label>
              <%= f.number_field :terms, :class => "form-control" %>      
            </fieldset>
          </div>   
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <fieldset class="property_create_group">         
              <label for="mortgage_interestRate">Interest</label>
              <%= f.number_field :interestRate, :class => "form-control" %>            
            </fieldset>
          </div>          
        </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
            <%= f.submit "Create mortgage", class: "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
          </div>         
      <% end %>
    </div><!-- /col-md-9-->
  </div><!-- /row-->
</div><!-- /container-->
```

**Mortgage.html:**

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/forms.css" />
 <script src="scripts/utils.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="scripts/mortgage.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content">
   <form action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset><label for="mname">Mortgage name</label>
     <input name="mname" id="mname" type="text" /></fieldset>
    <fieldset><label for="amount">Amount</label>
     <input name="amount" id="amount" type="text" /></fieldset>
    <fieldset><label for="terms">Terms</label>
     <input name="terms" id="terms" type="text" /></fieldset>
    <fieldset><label for="interestRate">Interest Rate</label>
     <input name="interestRate" id="interestRate" type="text" /></fieldset>
     <input type="submit" id="createMortgage" value="Create Mortgage" disabled="disabled"  />
    </fieldset>
   </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Mortgage.js:**

```
window.onload = initPage;

var warnings = {
  "mname" : {
    "required": "Please enter a name for your mortgage.",
    "err"     : 0
  },
  "amount" : {
    "required": "Please enter the amount of the mortgage.",
    "numbers" : "Only numbers are allowed in the mortgage amount.",
    "err"     : 0
  },
  "terms" : {
    "required": "Please enter the terms (in years) of the mortgage. ",
    "numbers" : "Only numbers (in years) can be given for the mortgage terms.",
    "err"     : 0
  },
  "interestRate" : {
    "required": "Please enter the amount of the interest rate.",
    "numbers" : "Only numbers are allowed in the interest rate.",
    "err"     : 0
  }
}

function initPage() {
  addEventHandler(document.getElementById("mname"), "blur", fieldIsFilled);
  addEventHandler(document.getElementById("amount"), "blur", fieldIsFilled);
  addEventHandler(document.getElementById("amount"), "blur", fieldIsNumbers);
  addEventHandler(document.getElementById("terms"), "blur", fieldIsFilled);
  addEventHandler(document.getElementById("terms"), "blur", fieldIsNumbers);
  addEventHandler(document.getElementById("interestRate"), "blur", fieldIsFilled);
  addEventHandler(document.getElementById("interestRate"), "blur", fieldIsNumbers);
}

function fieldIsFilled(e) {
  var me = getActivatedObject(e);
  if (me.value == "") {
    warn(me, "required");
  } else {
    unwarn(me, "required");
  }
}

function fieldIsLetters(e) {
  var me = getActivatedObject(e);
  var nonAlphaChars = /[^a-zA-Z]/;
  if (nonAlphaChars.test(me.value)) {
    warn(me, "letters");
  } else {
    unwarn(me, "letters");
  }
}

function fieldIsNumbers(e) {
  var me = getActivatedObject(e);
  var nonNumericChars = /[^0-9]/;
  if (nonNumericChars.test(me.value)) {
    warn(me, "numbers");
  } else {
    unwarn(me, "numbers");
  }
}

function warn(field, warningType) {
  var parentNode = field.parentNode;
  var warning = eval('warnings.' + field.id + '.' + warningType);
  if (parentNode.getElementsByTagName('p').length == 0) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    field.parentNode.appendChild(p);
    var warningNode = document.createTextNode(warning);
    p.appendChild(warningNode);
  } else {
    var p = parentNode.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
    p.childNodes[0].nodeValue = warning;
  }
  document.getElementById("createMortgage").disabled = true;
}

function unwarn(field, warningType) {
  if (field.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("p").length > 0) {
    var p = field.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
    var currentWarning = p.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var warning = eval('warnings.' + field.id + '.' + warningType);
    if (currentWarning == warning) {
      field.parentNode.removeChild(p);
    }
  }
  var fieldsets = 
    document.getElementById("content").getElementsByTagName("fieldset");
  for (var i=0; i<fieldsets.length; i++) {
    var fieldWarnings = fieldsets[i].getElementsByTagName("p").length;
    if (fieldWarnings > 0) {
      document.getElementById("createMortgage").disabled = true;
      return;
    }       
  }
  document.getElementById("createMortgage").disabled = false;
}
```

**Utils.js:**

```
function createRequest() {
  try {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } catch (tryMS) {
    try {
      request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (otherMS) {
      try {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (failed) {
        request = null;
      }
    }
  } 
  return request;
}


function getActivatedObject(e) {
  var obj;
  if (!e) {
    // early version of IE
    obj = window.event.srcElement;
  } else if (e.srcElement) {
    // IE 7 or later
    obj = e.srcElement;
  } else {
    // DOM Level 2 browser
    obj = e.target;
  }
  return obj;
}

function addEventHandler(obj, eventName, handler) {
  if (document.attachEvent) {
    obj.attachEvent("on" + eventName, handler);
  } else if (document.addEventListener) {
    obj.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
  }
}
```

Comment: I was too lazy to read all your code, but let me give you the advise to use jQuery so you can delete all that crap.

Answer (score 0):

You can try having a lok at client_side_validation gem. It is no longer maintained, but it should make your life easier without writing any additional js. https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations